# Boolean Deserialization Error

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am having problems with deserializeation for an XML element, I am assuming it is something to do with the namespace in the XML element not being found by the deserializer.

The data is coming form an outside source, which I cannot modify as a string and I am using C# 4.0.

Any help, gratefully appreciated.

```
string xml = "<boolean xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/serialization/\">false</boolean>";

var xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(bool));
using (var sr = new StringReader(xml)) 
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    var y = xSerializer.Deserialize(xr);
}
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
            ...
            ...
            ...
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<boolean xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/serialization/'> was not expected.
       Source=System.Xml
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationPrimitiveReader.Read_boolean()
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.DeserializePrimitive(XmlReader xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
            at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you create your serializer as below

```
var xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(bool),null, null, 
                         new XmlRootAttribute("boolean"), 
                         "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/serialization/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use xml namespaces and attributes if you want to deserialize a *boolean*. Infact you have to deserialize this:

```
string xml = "<boolean>false</boolean>";
```